# How to join two table with different value using Mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I Have two table:
Table 1 name: Buy

### Name  | Name code | Number |

a           01         25
  a           01         25
  b           02         75
  c           03         100
  c           03         25
And table 2 name: Sell

### Name  | Name code | Number |

b           02         60
  b           02         40
  c           03         80
  c           03         40
  d           04         45
  d           04         50

### So, how to  make two tables join like this (Using MYSQL Query):

### Name  | Name code | Number | Name | Name code | Number |

a           01         50 (SUM)    NULL     NULL       NULL
  b           02         75         b           02       100(SUM)
  c           03         125(SUM)    c           03       120(SUM)
  NULL       NULL        NULL 
      d         04         90(SUM)
When i type (SUM), it mean that value is SUM with 2 rows
Because this is so hard for me, so i need help so much
Please help me, i don't know how to do that. Thanks so much
And also if i need condition like b < 70 or C < 30 etc...

Comment: `SELECT table1.name, table1."name code", sum(table1.number) AS number, table2.name, table2."name code", sum(table2.number) AS number FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.name = table2.name GROUP BY table1.name, table2.name` Or something along these lines, I just wrote it blindly.

Comment: Actually, cancel that, that will clear the null rows. You need the full outer join instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit awkward because MySQL does not support full outer joins. EDIT because of bug:

```
SELECT B.name, B.name_code, B.total, S.name, S.name_code, S.total
FROM (
  SELECT name, name_code, SUM(number) AS total FROM buy GROUP BY name, name_code
) B LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT name, name_code, SUM(number) AS total FROM sell GROUP BY name, name_code
) S ON B.name = S.name
UNION
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, name, name_code, SUM(number) AS total FROM sell
WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM buy)
GROUP BY name, name_code;
```

Comment: But when i put duplicate value on bot table, the value return are wrong

Comment: Can you post example data where this happens, please?

Comment: This is link to image: [link]                                            https://imgur.com/1edhSmi                                          https://imgur.com/VF7J6IN                                                 
https://imgur.com/zxQyjzI

Comment: If we use this query: SELECT buy.name, buy.name_code, buy.number,
       sell.name, sell.name_code, sell.number
FROM buy LEFT JOIN sell ON buy.name = sell.name   
<br\>This is the result  <br\>https://imgur.com/sPSzrUV

Comment: I see. Your original data didn't have such an example so I didn't see the bug. How about now?

Comment: Ok thank U so much, it work for me very well ^^. Thank u so much, i'm very happy ^^

Comment: Hey @Amadan, can U write for me a query with "right join"? not with "union"?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_1.Name,table_1.Namecode ,SUM(table_1.Number),table_2.Name,

table_2.Namecode,SUM(table_2.Number)

FROM table_1 

FULL OUTER JOIN table_2

ON table_1.name = table_2.name

GROUP BY table_1.name,table_2.name
```

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL still does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, as I wrote in my answer.